# In how many ways can a group of 5 boys and 5 girls be seated in a row of 10 seats?

Tags: permutations, combinations

In how many ways can a group of 5 boys and 5 girls be seated in a row of 10 seats?

Still having some confusion with the difference between combinations and permutations. I have tried this problem using both combination and permutation with the formulas and my calculator and neither were correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

Ladies first: choose $5$ fixed places for the girls: $\binom{10}{5}$ - this (number of combinations) does not account for the order of the girls, whom you can permute in $5!$ ways. There are $5$ remaining places for the boys: Again, we can permute them in $5!$ ways. So the number is
$$\binom{10}{5}\cdot 5!\cdot 5!=\ldots$$
You shouldn't find it surprising that the answer is $10!$ - that's because you are in fact permuting $10$ people over $10$ seats, no matter who is boy or girl.

Comment: Why does the order not matter?

Comment: Bad wording, corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the rigid formulas, try to use your own logic.

10 human can sit on 10 seats in 10! ways.

But, we are only curious only for the boy-girl ordering, thus if only the ordering of the boys, or the ordering of the girls differ, it is the same case.

The 5 boys can seat 5! ways (between the girls) and the 5 girls can seat also 5! ways (between the boys).

Thus, we calculated every case 5!*5! times into this 10! result.

Thus, the real result is $\frac{10!}{5! \cdot 5!}=252$.